# Vectorize Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: compiler-construction, graph-theory

I have an ast of an expression. I would like to vectorize it, so I can calculate as much as possible in parallel. Obviously this only works if the nodes are independent.

If I think this in graph theory, I want to merge as many nodes (of the same operator) as possible, without getting intersections. I don't think there's "one perfect solution". Probably needs some heuristics.

Is there an algorithm for this? What's the approach?

My strategy right now, I pick the "heaviest" nodes (such as SIN / COS / EXP..). And keep merging two together and remove them from the graph. This works okeysh.

Comment: See the SLP vectoriser in LLVM.

Comment: Thank you @SK-logic for the hint, I found this paper: [link](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/cag/slp/SLP-PLDI-2000.pdf), which talks exactly about what I want to do.